# Ubuntu 20.04 not starting without nomodeset on Lenovo Titanium

Tags: grub2, lenovo, nomodeset

I am not able to start Ubuntu 20.04 without nomodeset in grub on Lenovo X1 Titanium Yoga

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

gives

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a40 (rev 01)
```

Comment: I unfortunately have no solution yet but I have the same issue. [There's some conversation in this thread on lenovo's official support page that might help.](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/Ubuntu-on-X1-Titanium-Yoga/m-p/5076885) That thread seems to indicate that this is a known issue with the hardware. My logs are posted on that thread. [dmesg with no grub params](https://pastebin.com/sBQby0Ap)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by applying this patch: https://crazy.dev.frugalware.org/Intel-i915-backport-MSO-fixes-to-kernel-5.12.patch
to the 5.12 kernel source from here https://github.com/xanmod/linux.

This sounds difficult but is fairly easy. Takes around 10 minutes of work (and another hour where your computer works for you).

The result is a kernel that seems to work nicely with Pop!_OS, so it should also work with Ubuntu and other Debian-based systems that can run xanmod kernels. Detailed steps how this is done are found here: https://gist.github.com/simonheb/b54b91358c3d7e2960a4f6e13e95ac54