# Intel Iris Xe, laggy performance in 20.04 LTS, and also in 21.04

Tags: 20.04, intel-graphics, ubuntu-gnome, 21.04

I am using a new Thinkpad X1 Titanium Yoga with an integrated Intel Iris Xe and an i5 processor (11th Gen, 1140G7). I've tried Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and 21.04 without further changes, and currently use Pop!_OS 20.10.

Unless I boot with the additional `nomodeset` kernel option the screen stays black. Irrespective of that, performance is sub-optimal. Hardware accelerations seems off.

I tried different Kernels. So far no success. This is the output of `inxi`:

```
shess@pop-os:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa 
  resolution: 2256x1504~95Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.0.0 
shess@pop-os:~$ uname -r
5.10.0-1023-oem
```

Comment: I have this in my notes: Gen12 Xe Graphics might not be working out-of-the-box depending upon your kernel. 
Re-booting the system while having "i915.force_probe=4c8a" Some distribution kernels including the likes of Ubuntu are already carrying the patch 
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-rkl-linux&num=1
Please don't mention i915.force_probe in end-user documentation #980 
https://github.com/intel/media-driver/issues/980 & 
https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/DRM_I915_FORCE_PROBE.html
https://www.mail-archive.com/intel-gfx@lists.freedesktop.org/msg191190.html

Comment: Thanks @oldfred. Sadly, passing  "i915.force_probe=4c8a"  as kernel boot parameter did not work. Also passing  "i915.force_probe=9a40" (which seems to be my card based on `lspci`) did not help. Do you know if on a 5.11 kernel I have to use a different way to specify tihis?

Comment: not know anymore. Just saw this were 5.12 has an improvement for Xe. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.12-Released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by applying this patch: https://crazy.dev.frugalware.org/Intel-i915-backport-MSO-fixes-to-kernel-5.12.patch
against the 5.12 kernel source from here https://github.com/xanmod/linux
This sounds difficult but is fairly easy. Takes around 10 minutes of work (and another hour where your computer works).

The result is a kernel that seems to work nicely with Pop!_OS, so it should also work with Ubuntu and other Debian-based systems that can run xanmod kernels. Detailed steps how this is done are found here: https://gist.github.com/simonheb/b54b91358c3d7e2960a4f6e13e95ac54

Answer (score 3):

When you run with nomodeset you disable the intel graphics driver, which is why the lag is so bad. You should see a message indicating that in your dmesg output: `sudo dmesg | grep nomodeset`. But I'm experiencing the same thing, and also have bad screen update problems (eg. I click between tabs and the content of the last tab stays visible until I scroll), but I'm hoping this will go away once I can boot with the gpu enabled.

```
➜  graphics_debug sudo dmesg | grep nomodeset                                         
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.12.0-051200rc7-generic root=UUID=785c4ea2-4122-4f4b-b6b2-28e123b6f5bc ro nomodeset
[    0.085047] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.12.0-051200rc7-generic root=UUID=785c4ea2-4122-4f4b-b6b2-28e123b6f5bc ro nomodeset
[    0.085104] You have booted with nomodeset. This means your GPU drivers are DISABLED
[    0.085107] Unless you actually understand what nomodeset does, you should reboot without enabling it
```

There's another thread on this here:
[Ubuntu 20.04 not starting without nomodeset on Lenovo Titanium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333303/ubuntu-20-04-not-starting-without-nomodeset-on-lenovo-titanium)

Comment: Thanks. Don't know what I can do except the `nomodeset`, because if I don't do this, it does not boot.... or are you suggesting to drop the `nomodeset` when I try the  `i915.force_probe=9a40`? I am currently not at home so I cannot try this. Have you?

Comment: Is it true though that `nodemodeset` "disables the intel graphics driver"? Isn't it rather the case that the modesetting just happens at a later stage and not from within the kernel? See: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Comment: I posted the dmesg output when running with `nomodeset` above. On the 3rd line it says "This means your GPU drivers are DISABLED". I agree though that the docs don't really indicate that, but I think it might have something to do with the interaction with the intel integrated graphics vs. dedicated cards.

Comment: Re. what to try, I'm not sure tbh. I've been through a lot of debugging based on suggestions for different hardware without success, but my gut feeling is that since the laptop is so new, it needs an official support fix. I think adding i915.force_prob=9a40 option without nodmodeset is worth a shot though, will try it later.

Comment: @sheß don't use your card's id, use a different one

Comment: @Ray Wu, what do you mean with "a different one"? which one and why?